# Hiding content in Chrome settings using Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I am attempting to hide the "Show" button in Chrome's manage passwords page that shows passwords in plain-text. I don't want this to turn into any sort of security discussion - I just have no use for Chrome to ever show me my passwords.

Since it seemed like just another page to Chrome (`chrome://settings/passwords`), I decided to try to mess with the settings page using Tampermonkey. I have no use for that password field at all, so I tried to hide anything with the class "password":

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Get rid of 'Show Password' button
// @namespace  
// @version    0.1
// @description  nope
// @match      chrome://settings/passwords
// @copyright  2012+, You
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
//
// ==/UserScript==

jQuery(function($) {
    $(".password").hide();
});
```

This doesn't work, though. I tried messing around with the page using the console, but I think the settings page has some sort of security that keeps me from even selecting the relevant page elements.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update**
>   Support for `Custom.css` has been removed from Chrome in version 32.
>   See [this answer](/questions/21207474#answer-21210882).

User scripts can't access `chrome:` scheme. To hide 'Show' button in Chrome password manager, add this CSS code to `\User StyleSheets\Custom.css` file in your [profile folder](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).

```
#password-manager .list-inline-button.custom-appearance { display: none; }
```